# Integral involving power, exponential and confluent hypergeometric function

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, hypergeometric-function

**I am seeking a solution for the following integral:**
\begin{equation}
\int\frac{e^{-\beta t}}{t}\,U(a,b,t) \,\mathrm{d}t
\end{equation}
where $0<\beta<1$, $a<1$, $b<2$, and $U(a,b,t)$ is the [confluent hypergeometric function of the 2nd kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConfluentHypergeometricFunctionoftheSecondKind.html). I have already solved this integral for $a=0,-1,-2,\dots$

---

> **Motivation for asking this question:**
>
> I am trying to compute the following Cauchy principal valued integral
>   \begin{equation}
> \lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^{+}}\int_{\varepsilon}^{\infty}\frac{1}{t}\left(\frac{e^{-\beta_{1} t}}{\Gamma(\alpha_{1})}U(1-\alpha_{1},2-\alpha_{3},\beta_{3}t)
> -
> \frac{e^{-\beta_{2} t}}{\Gamma(\alpha_{2})}U(1-\alpha_{2},2-\alpha_{3},\beta_{3}t)
> \right)\mathrm{d}t,
> \end{equation}
>   where $\alpha_{1},\alpha_{2},\beta_{1},\beta_{2}>0$, $\alpha_{3}=\alpha_{1}+\alpha_{2}$, and $\beta_{3}=\beta_{1}+\beta_{2}$. I have already solved this integral for the following increasingly general special cases:
>
> $\qquad(1).\ \ $ $\alpha_{1}=\alpha_{2}$ and $\beta_{1}=\beta_{2}$ (trivial case).
>
> $\qquad(2).\ \ $ $\alpha_{1}=\alpha_{2}=1$.
>
> $\qquad(3).\ \ $ $\alpha_{1}\in\mathbb{N}^{+}$ and $\alpha_{2}\in\mathbb{N}^{+}$.
>
> My ultimate goal is to find the solution for $\alpha_{1},\alpha_{2}\in\mathbb{R}^{+}$.

Comment: Can you point me to, or explain, how you did $a=0,−1,−2,…$ ?  I have been working on a generic solution and while making progress, I haven't managed it.  So I am interested in alternative approaches, and I might have an alternate one for you.  In any case, you might try a Riordan Array Transform approach; although I have reached a stumbling block and am awaiting inspiration.

Comment: @rrogers give me a minute to write it up. I will append the solution for non-positive integer $a$ to the end of the post.

Comment: @rrogers Just posted solution for $a=0,-1,-2,\dots$ I appreciate the feedback.  I have not heard of the Riordan Array Transform (I am just an amateur) but I will look into it. Btw, for $b\in\mathbb{Z}$ you can write $U(a,b,t)$ in terms of the sum of two $M(a,b,t)$'s.  That may also help for that special case.  Hopefully this will give you some inspiration!

Comment: One thing I don't understand is why you didn't differentiate the original expression with respect to $\beta$ to get rid of the 1/t term; then integrate at the end? You can go to the polynomial directly via http://dlmf.nist.gov/13.2.E7 and subsequent special cases.  Also, the conversion from U->M can usually be done via http://dlmf.nist.gov/13.2.E42  ; except when b is an integer.  (Actually there are a lot of cases that drive people mad and into error)

Comment: @rrogers That's just what I tried first since I knew that $U(a,b,t)$ would be a polynomial.

Comment: Well then you would just have the Laplace Transform, for instance, http://dlmf.nist.gov/13.10.E7.  You do have to take the asymptotic expansion around zero or one of the transforms at http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.8

Comment: @rrogers I am not entirely sure I understand.  I can see how you can take the derivative w.r.t. $\beta$ then use the formula for the Laplace transform. I appended that bit to the end of the question.  Are you saying to compute an expansion around $b=0$?  Or try to match what I have to one of the transformations in DLMF 15.8? Not really sure what you're envisioning here.  Thank you.

Comment: Actually, I made a wrong turn; how about skipping the derivative and just using b=0 and then the Laplace transform?  That's your answer with the problems at z=0.  That's the reason I suggested transform or asymptotics.  I think the "hall monitors" are going to move this conversation somewhere unless I quit this conversation; sorry.

Comment: @rrogers Unfortunately the Laplace transform requires $b>0$. Maybe use solution of Laplace trans. and write it as $\lim_{b\to 0^{+}}$? Not sure. Seems like the solution is within reach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We begin with the following Cauchy principal value integral:
\begin{equation}
\tag{1}
I=
\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}
\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha_{1})}\int_{\varepsilon}^{1/\varepsilon}
e^{-\beta_{1}y}\,y^{-1}\,U(1-\alpha_{1},2-\alpha_{3},\beta_{3}y)
\,\mathrm{d}y\\
-
\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha_{2})}\int_{\varepsilon}^{1/\varepsilon}
e^{-\beta_{2}y}\,y^{-1}\,U(1-\alpha_{2},2-\alpha_{3},\beta_{3}y)
\,\mathrm{d}y\,,
\end{equation}
where $\alpha_{1},\alpha_{2},\beta_{1},\beta_{2}>0$, $\alpha_{3}=\alpha_{1}+\alpha_{2}$, and $\beta_{3}=\beta_{1}+\beta_{2}$. 
In the pursuit of a closed-form expression for $I$ we attack these integrals from another direction, namely, by increasing the power component of the integrands by small positive constant $\varepsilon$, i.e. $y^{\varepsilon-1}$, which subsequently allows the limits of integration to extend over the interval $y\in[0,\infty)$ without causing the integrals to diverge. With a substitution of $t=\beta_{3}y$, the expression for $I$ is rewritten as
\begin{equation}
\tag{2}
I=
\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\,
\frac{\beta_{3}^{-\varepsilon}}{\Gamma(\alpha_{1})}\int_{0}^{\infty}
\exp\left(-\tfrac{\beta_{1}}{\beta_{3}}t\right)\,t^{\varepsilon-1}\,U(1-\alpha_{1},2-\alpha_{3},t)
\,\mathrm{d}t\\
-
\frac{\beta_{3}^{-\varepsilon}}{\Gamma(\alpha_{2})}\int_{0}^{\infty}
\exp\left(-\tfrac{\beta_{2}}{\beta_{3}}t\right)\,t^{\varepsilon-1}\,U(1-\alpha_{2},2-\alpha_{3},t)
\,\mathrm{d}t\,,
\end{equation}
which now puts it into the form of [DLMF 13.10.7](http://dlmf.nist.gov/13.10.E7):
\begin{equation}
\tag{3}
\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-zt}t^{\varepsilon-1}U(a,b,t)\,\mathrm{d}t=\frac{\Gamma(\varepsilon)\Gamma(\varepsilon-b+1)}{\Gamma(a-b+1+\varepsilon)}z^{-\varepsilon}
{_{2}F_{1}}\left(a,\varepsilon;a-b+1+\varepsilon;1-\tfrac{1}{z}\right),
\end{equation}
for $\Re\varepsilon>\max(\Re b-1,0)$, and $\Re z>0$. Since $\varepsilon$ is going to ultimately approach zero, use of this formula requires that $\alpha_{3}>1$. Nevertheless, making use of the formula $I$ assumes the form of
\begin{equation}
\tag{4}
I=
\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}
C\Gamma(\varepsilon)
\left(
\frac{{_{2}F_{1}}\left(1-\alpha_{1},\varepsilon;\alpha_{2}+\varepsilon;-\tfrac{\beta_{2}}{\beta_{1}}\right)}{\Gamma(\alpha_{1})\Gamma(\alpha_{2}+\varepsilon)\beta_{1}^{\varepsilon}}
-
\frac{{_{2}F_{1}}\left(1-\alpha_{2},\varepsilon;\alpha_{1}+\varepsilon;-\tfrac{\beta_{1}}{\beta_{2}}\right)}{\Gamma(\alpha_{1}+\varepsilon)\Gamma(\alpha_{2})\beta_{2}^{\varepsilon}}
\right),
\end{equation}
where $C=\Gamma(\alpha_{3}-1)$. It is clear that the $\Gamma(\varepsilon)$ term is the only term that diverges as $\varepsilon\to0$. Therefore to help simplify the limit, consider for a moment the Laurent series of the gamma function about the origin
\begin{equation}
\tag{5}
\Gamma(\varepsilon)=\frac{1}{\varepsilon}-\gamma+\mathcal{O}(\varepsilon)\qquad\text{for}\ |\varepsilon|<1\land\varepsilon\neq0\,,
\end{equation}
Since the limit of the quantity $(\cdots-\cdots)$ in Eq. $4$ yields zero, the constant and $\mathcal{O}(\varepsilon)$ terms can be dropped; thus, $\Gamma(\varepsilon)$ is replaced by $1/\varepsilon$ which puts the entire limit into a $0/0$ indeterminant form. As a consequence, L'Hopital's rule is applied resulting in
\begin{equation}
\tag{6}
I=
\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}
\frac{\partial}{\partial\varepsilon}C
\left(
\frac{{_{2}F_{1}}\left(1-\alpha_{1},\varepsilon;\alpha_{2}+\varepsilon;-\tfrac{\beta_{2}}{\beta_{1}}\right)}{\Gamma(\alpha_{1})\Gamma(\alpha_{2}+\varepsilon)\beta_{1}^{\varepsilon}}
-
\frac{{_{2}F_{1}}\left(1-\alpha_{2},\varepsilon;\alpha_{1}+\varepsilon;-\tfrac{\beta_{1}}{\beta_{2}}\right)}{\Gamma(\alpha_{1}+\varepsilon)\Gamma(\alpha_{2})\beta_{2}^{\varepsilon}}
\right).
\end{equation}

For the sake of brevity, we will define the following functions:
\begin{gather}
f_{1}(\varepsilon) = {_{2}F_{1}}\left(1-\alpha_{1},\varepsilon;\alpha_{2}+\varepsilon;-\tfrac{\beta_{2}}{\beta_{1}}\right),\\
f_{2}(\varepsilon) = {_{2}F_{1}}\left(1-\alpha_{2},\varepsilon;\alpha_{1}+\varepsilon;-\tfrac{\beta_{1}}{\beta_{2}}\right),\\
g_{1}(\varepsilon) = \Gamma(\alpha_{1})\Gamma(\alpha_{2}+\varepsilon)\beta_{1}^{\varepsilon},\\
g_{2}(\varepsilon) = \Gamma(\alpha_{1}+\varepsilon)\Gamma(\alpha_{2})\beta_{2}^{\varepsilon},
\end{gather}
and then compute the derivative in Eq. $6$ to arrive at
\begin{equation}
\tag{7}
I=
\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}C
\left(
\frac{f_{1}^{\prime}(\varepsilon)}{g_{1}(\varepsilon)}
-
\frac{f_{1}(\varepsilon)\, g_{1}^{\prime}(\varepsilon)}{g_{1}^{2}(\varepsilon)}
-
\frac{f_{2}^{\prime}(\varepsilon)}{g_{2}(\varepsilon)}
+
\frac{f_{2}(\varepsilon)\, g_{2}^{\prime}(\varepsilon)}{g_{2}^{2}(\varepsilon)}
\right).
\end{equation}

At this point all that is left to do is find the limits of the functions $f_{1}$, $f_{2}$, $g_{1}$, and $g_{2}$ and their corresponding derivatives. Starting with the function $g(\varepsilon)=\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b+\varepsilon)c^{\varepsilon}$ which is of the same form as $g_{1}$ and $g_{2}$ it is straightforward to show that
\begin{equation}
\tag{8}
\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}g(\varepsilon)=
\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b),
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\tag{9}
\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}g^{\prime}(\varepsilon)=
\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)(\psi(b)+\log c),
\end{equation}
where $\psi(z)$ is the digamma function. Next, we consider the function $f(\varepsilon)={_{2}F_{1}}\left(1-a,\varepsilon;b+\varepsilon;-c/d\right)$ which is of the same form as $f_{1}$ and $f_{2}$. Writing $f$ using it's power series representation we find 
\begin{equation}
\tag{10}
\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}
f(\varepsilon)=
\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}
1+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(1-a)_{k}(\varepsilon)_{k}}{(b+\varepsilon)_{k}\,k!}\,\left(-\frac{c}{d}\right)^{k}=1\,.
\end{equation}
For $\lim_{\varepsilon\to}f^{\prime}(\varepsilon)$, we first compute the derivative of each term yielding
\begin{equation}
\tag{11}
\frac{\partial}{\partial\varepsilon}
\frac{\theta_{k}\,(\varepsilon)_{k}}{(b+\varepsilon)_{k}}=
\frac{\theta_{k}\,(\varepsilon)_{k}}{(b+\varepsilon)_{k}}(\psi(b+\varepsilon)-\psi(\varepsilon)+\psi(k+\varepsilon)-\psi(b+k+\varepsilon))\,.
\end{equation}
where $\theta_{k}$ is the constant part of each term w.r.t. $\varepsilon$. In the limit, all of the $\psi(\cdots+\varepsilon)$ terms can be dropped since $\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}(\varepsilon)_{k}=0$ leaving
\begin{equation}
\tag{12}
\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}
\frac{\partial}{\partial\varepsilon}
\frac{\theta_{k}\,(\varepsilon)_{k}}{(b+\varepsilon)_{k}}=
-\theta_{k}\frac{\Gamma(k)}{(b)_{k}}\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\frac{\psi(\varepsilon)}{\Gamma(\varepsilon)}\,.
\end{equation}
Now consider the following asymptotically equivalent forms for $\varepsilon\approx0$:
\begin{gather}
\tag{13}
\psi(\varepsilon)=-\frac{1}{\varepsilon}-\gamma+\mathcal{O}(\varepsilon)\,,\\
\tag{14}
\frac{1}{\Gamma(\varepsilon)}=\varepsilon+\mathcal{O}(\varepsilon^{2})\,.
\end{gather}
From these limiting forms it is clear that the remaining limit in Eq. $12$ is equal to $-1$ such that
\begin{equation}
\tag{14}
\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}
f^{\prime}(\varepsilon) =
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(1-a)_{k}}{k!}\left(-\frac{c}{d}\right)^{k}\frac{\Gamma(k)}{(b)_{k}}\,.
\end{equation}
Shifting the index down to start at $k=0$ and then simplifying yields
\begin{equation}
\tag{15}
\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}
f^{\prime}(\varepsilon) =
\frac{(a-1)\,c}{b\,d}
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2-a)_{k}(1)_{k}(1)_{k}}{(1+b)_{k}(2)_{k}}\,\frac{1}{k!} \left(-\frac{c}{d}\right)^{k},
\end{equation}
which is now in the form of the [generalized hypergeometric function](http://dlmf.nist.gov/16.2.E1).  Thus
\begin{equation}
\tag{16}
\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}
f^{\prime}(\varepsilon) =
\frac{(a-1)\,c}{b\,d}
{_{3}F_{2}}\left(2-a,1,1;1+b,2;-\tfrac{c}{d}\right),
\end{equation}
where ${_{p}}F_{q}(a_{1},\dots,a_{p};b_{1},\dots,b_{q};z)$ is the generalized hypergeometric function. It is important to note that if $2-a\neq 0,-1,-2,\dots$, the series in Eq. $15$ only converges for $|c/d|<1$; therefore, for $|c/d|\geq 1$ the result of Eq. $16$ is defined by the analytic continuation of ${_{3}F_{2}}(\cdots;z)$ w.r.t. $z$. With these results at hand, the limit of each component in Eq. $7$ is solved yielding the final solution for $I$ when $\alpha_{3}>1$:
\begin{multline}
\tag{17}
I=
C\biggl(
\log\tfrac{\beta_{2}}{\beta_{1}}+\psi(\alpha_{1})-\psi(\alpha_{2})
+
\tfrac{(\alpha_{1}-1)\,\beta_{2}}{\alpha_{2}\,\beta_{1}}{_{3}F_{2}}\left(2-\alpha_{1},1,1;1+\alpha_{2},2;-\tfrac{\beta_{2}}{\beta_{1}}\right)\\
-
\tfrac{(\alpha_{2}-1)\,\beta_{1}}{\alpha_{1}\,\beta_{2}}{_{3}F_{2}}\left(2-\alpha_{2},1,1;1+\alpha_{1},2;-\tfrac{\beta_{1}}{\beta_{2}}\right)
\biggr),
\end{multline}
where
\begin{equation}
C =
\frac{\Gamma(\alpha_{3}-1)}
{\Gamma(\alpha_{1})\Gamma(\alpha_{2})}.
\end{equation}

Comment: I am having a problem with eq (4); what happened to $\beta_{3}$ ?  In other words where did $\beta_{1}/ \beta_{2}$ come form?

Comment: @rrogers Two things going on here. The $\beta_{3}^{-\varepsilon}$ cancels with the $z^{-\varepsilon}$ since $z=\beta_{i}/\beta_{3}$. As for the ${_{2}F_{1}}(\cdots;-\beta_{1}/\beta_{2})$, that comes about because $\beta_{3}=\beta_{1}+\beta_{2}$. So $1-\tfrac{1}{z}=1-\beta_{3}/\beta_{2}$ substituting we get $1-(\beta_{1}+\beta_{2})/\beta_{2}=1-\beta_{1}/\beta_{2}-1$ and thus we get the answer $-\beta_{1}/\beta_{2}$

Answer (score 1):

If you consider this not to a relevant answer, just tell me and I will delete it.  Of course, constructive remarks are always welcome.
Be aware that $U()$ has a lot of special cases (computational branch points) that I have ignored in favour of what I consider typical. If you have special cases of interest that makes this blow up, I will try to look into them.
An equation is:${\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\infty}}t^{s-1}e^{-\alpha t}U\left(a,b,\lambda\cdot t\right)dt$
Using Mellin transform interpretation of 
http://dlmf.nist.gov/13.10#E7
${\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\infty}}t^{s-1}e^{-z\cdot t}U\left(a,c,t\right)dt=\Gamma\left(s\right)\cdot\Gamma\left(s-c+1\right)\cdot z^{-s}\cdot\,_{2}F_{1}\left(a,s;a+s-c+1;1-\frac{1}{z}\right)$
Requiring $\mathbb{\mathcal{R}}\left(z\right)>0,\mathcal{R}\left(s\right)>max\left(\mathbb{\mathcal{R}}\left(c\right),0\right)$
We can examine the terms of the right hand side and make sure the power series expansion matches up after inversion on a term by term basis. Failure of the inverse Mellin transform implies that when $\mathcal{R}\left(s\right)\leq0$ either the closure of the contour around the left hand poles fails because of essential or logarithmic singularity ; or because of the problem of the obvious pole/zero cancellation. But let's just move the goal posts a little using http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.5.E15 and some substitution
$_{2}F_{1}\left(a,s;a+s-c+1;1-\frac{1}{z}\right)=\left(1-\frac{b}{c}\right)\cdot\left(1-\frac{1}{z}\right)\cdot\,_{2}F_{1}\left(a,s+1;a+s-c+2;1-\frac{1}{z}\right)-\frac{1}{z}\cdot\,_{2}F_{1}\left(a,s+1;a+s-c+1;1-\frac{1}{z}\right)$
$\Gamma\left(s\right)\cdot\Gamma\left(s-c+1\right)\Rightarrow\frac{\Gamma\left(s+1\right)}{s}\cdot\Gamma\left(s-c+1\right)$
Which pulls out $\frac{1}{s}$ as a simple pole and the other terms are well behaved. In fact we can recognize the alteration as almost a simple integration.
Now I can probably pull this back to two integrals of $\int e^{-z\cdot t}U(..)$ and do a term by term check; but given the complexity of the series expansion $U()$ you probably won't like it and I would put it in a link. An alternative is rearrange the original to $U()=M()\cdot...+M()\cdot...$ using http://dlmf.nist.gov/13.2.E42. But that has the restriction on c not be an integer.
Yet another alternative is using “Cauchy principal value” which, as I recall, deals with this sort of thing for the Casimir effect. I think I can find the usage explanation and usage in an MAA article.

Comment: Based on your comments I believe I see the path forward to a solution.  I updated the question to show the reasoning behind it. The final answer just requires (hopefully) a limit! Thank you for your helpful comments.

Comment: I have found a closed-form to the limit I left at the end of my question yesterday. The solution has been verified against numerical integration.  Will post solution once I clean it up. Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Looking forward to it.

Comment: Can I send it to you directly? I dont believe SE has that capability but I can send it via email. Its part of a larger manuscript I am putting together.  You might find it interesting. Also, I am still trying to solve the question for $0<\alpha_{3}\leq1$. I believe the answer may be $\infty$...just haven't proven it yet.

Comment: Posted the solution.

Comment: PLease read readme.txt at https://www.dropbox.com/sh/qzjas6jza3o7imx/AACjLPX3U9bUnt1wN4p_IKgNa?dl=0

Comment: @AaronHendrickson  try https://www.dropbox.com/s/f9druod366g410z/readme.txt?dl=0

Comment: Got it. You can remove the link now if you want to.